# ¿Como puedo tener sub-rutas en ionic 7 con react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, ionic-framework

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Ionic 7 y react. Y estoy queriendo saber como proteger por ejemplo que al entrar en /dashboard verifique si hay token y a partir de /dashboard tenga como sub rutas, por ejemplo /dashboard/settings.

Lo que necesito saber es como hago para que settings sea un hijo de dashboard, y que solo se verifique el token en /dashboard y no en todas las sub-rutas de dashboard.